# Poker probability in Python with input file

Tags: python, methods, probability, poker

I'm trying to find out how I can find the probability of a hand with whatever the next card would be. I don't know how to check for the next card and get the probability nor do I know what to do to write it all together into separate methods for each kind of hand. Any help for me to be able to read in a card to the hand and find the probability of getting that hand would be greatly appreciated.

> Write a program that reads in a text file. The name will be supplied
>   as a command-line parameter. Each line gives you a list of 4 cards in
>   your current hand. After reading in the file, your program will print
>   out the probability of each type of winning hand, where a winning hand
>   is given

```
import sys
#error message
if len (sys.argv) == 1:
    print "Error"
    exit()
file = sys.argv[1]
#counts and arrays
#count = 0

f = open(file)
f = f.read()
hand = f.splitlines()
arraynum = 0
def deck():
    deck = []
    suit = ['H', 'S', 'D', 'C']
    number = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    for s in suit:
        for n in number:
            deck.append(n+s)
    return deck

def startHand(arraynum):
    hand1 = str(hand[arraynum]).split(', ')
    hand1.sort()
    return hand1

def checkHand(deck,hand1):
    for card in hand1:
        for Card in deck:
            if Card == card:
                deck.remove(card)
    return deck

def check1(deck, hand1):
    count = 0
    for Card in deck:
        for i in hand1[0:-1]:
            if i != Card:
                count +=1
    prob = count / 48
    print prob
    print count


t1 = deck()
t2 = startHand(3)
t3 = checkHand(t1,t2)
t4 = check1(t2,t3)'
```

The input file is:
    QS, JS, KS, 10S
    KS, 3C, 3S, QC
    6D, 10D, AD, 7D

the output should look like:

```
('Chance of Royal Flush: ', 0.020833333333333332)
('Chance of Straight Flush: ', 0.020833333333333332)
('Chance of Four of a Kind: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Full House: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Flush: ', 0.14583333333333334)
('Chance of Straight: ', 0.125)
('Chance of Three of a Kind: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Two Pair: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Pair: ', 0.25)
('Chance of High Card: ', 0.4375)
*************************************

('Chance of Royal Flush: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Straight Flush: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Four of a Kind: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Full House: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Flush: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Straight: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Three of a Kind: ', 0.041666666666666664)
('Chance of Two Pair: ', 0.125)
('Chance of Pair: ', 0.8333333333333334)
('Chance of High Card: ', 0.0)
*************************************

('Chance of Royal Flush: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Straight Flush: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Four of a Kind: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Full House: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Flush: ', 0.1875)
('Chance of Straight: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Three of a Kind: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Two Pair: ', 0.0)
('Chance of Pair: ', 0.25)
('Chance of High Card: ', 0.5625)
*************************************
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should get you started and is implemented on python 3.5.  It'll provide the framework
for what it is you need to do.  Note that you don't need to bother with the 
deck.  The input cards are read from the text file as given but are then mapped
into a sequence of numbers for easier processing.

You'll have to implement the rest as it's incomplete.  Hope that helps and
good luck.

```
# Probability calculation examples are given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability

import sys
from math import factorial

if len (sys.argv) == 1:
    print("Error")
    exit()
file = sys.argv[1]

cnv={'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,
     '9':9,'10':10,'J':11,'Q':12,'K':13,'A':14}

f = open(file)
input = f.read()
inCards = [x.strip() for x in input.split(',')]
cards=[{card[-1:] : cnv[card[0:-1]]} for card in inCards]
print("All cards from input list=",cards,"\n\n")

# Removes num cards from input list and returns them
def getCards(cards,num):
    hand=cards[0:num]
    del cards[0:num]
    return hand

# Finds the suit with the most cards
def maxSuit(suitSeq):
    mv=0
    for k,vList in suitSeq.items(): 
      if len(vList) > mv:
        mv=len(vList)
        mk=k
    return mk,mv

def seqGapsSize(suitList):
    cumGapSizes=0
    for i in range(1,len(suitList)):
      cumGapSizes+=suitList[i]-suitList[i-1]-1
    return cumGapSizes

# Return a dict with just non-empty suits
def nonEmptySuits(suitSeq):
    suits={}
    for k,vList in suitSeq.items(): 
      if len(vList) > 0:
        suits[k]=vList
    return suits

# Returns a dictionary with keys of card values (ie 2,3..J,K)
# across all suits and the # of times they occur in the hand.
def sameCardDict(suitSeq):
    d={}
    for k,vList in suitSeq.items(): 
      for v in vList:
        if v in d:
          d[v]+=1
        else:
          d[v]=1
    return d

def getAllGaps(suits):
    gaps=0
    for k,vList in suits.items():
        gaps+=seqGapsSize(vList)
    return gaps

def royalFlushProb(suitSeq,numCards):
    k,vnum=maxSuit(suitSeq)
    if vnum!=numCards or seqGapsSize(suitSeq[k])>(5-numCards): return 0.0
    if not set(suitSeq[k]) < set([10,11,12,13,14]): return 0.0
    return 1.0/nChoosek(52-numCards,5-numCards)

def straightFlushProb(suitSeq,numCards):
    k,vnum=maxSuit(suitSeq)
    if vnum!=numCards or seqGapsSize(suitSeq[k])>(5-numCards):
       return 0.0
    return 1.0/nChoosek(52-numCards,5-numCards)

def fourOfAKindProb(suitSeq,numCards):
    dict=sameCardDict(suitSeq)
    maxSameNum=max(dict,key=dict.get)
    if dict[maxSameNum]<numCards-1: return 0.0
    return 1.0/(nChoosek(13,1)+nChoosek(12,1))

def fullHouseProb(suitSeq,numCards):
    suits=nonEmptySuits(suitSeq)
    # Need at least 2 suits for 4 cards
    if len(suits.keys())<(5-numCards)+1: return 0.0
    # Same card in all suits means there should be no gaps
    if (getAllGaps(suits)!=0): return 0.0
    return 1.0/(nChoosek(13,1)*nChoosek(2,1)+nChoosek(12,1)*nChoosek(3,1))

def findSeq(hand):
    suitSeq={'C':[],'H':[],'D':[],'S':[]}
    for c in hand:
      for k,v in c.items(): 
          suitSeq[k].append(v)
      suitSeq[k].sort()       
    return suitSeq

def nChoosek(n,k):
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))

def computeAndPrintProbs(suitSeq,numCards): 
    print('Chance of Royal Flush: ', royalFlushProb(suitSeq,numCards))
    print('Chance of Straight Flush: ', straightFlushProb(suitSeq,numCards))
    print('Chance of Four of a Kind: ', fourOfAKindProb(suitSeq,numCards))
    print('Chance of Full House: ', fullHouseProb(suitSeq,numCards))
    print('Chance of Flush: ', )
    print('Chance of Straight: ', )
    print('Chance of Three of a Kind: ', )
    print('Chance of Two Pair: ', )
    print('Chance of Pair: ', )
    print('Chance of High Card: ', )
    print('*'*30,"\n"*2)

numCards=4
for i in range(1,4):
  hand=getCards(cards,numCards)
  print("Input hand on this round: ",hand)
  suitSeq=findSeq(hand)
  print("Hand re-organized for processing: ",suitSeq,"\n")
  computeAndPrintProbs(suitSeq,numCards)
```